# Spec2: Getting second parameter argument passed into the mocked method invocation

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, matcher, specs2

I have a mocked service which takes 3 parameters. How do I access second argument?

```
mockedService.invoke(arg1, arg2, arg3) answers {
  (params, mock) => {
     //Do something with params.arg2 to the value that is returned from the invocation
  }
}
```

In the documentation, they states *"the array of the method parameters will be passed"* how do I access the second argument (`arg2` in this case)? Do I cast `params` with `List[Any]`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match the parameters to an `Array` like this:

```
import org.specs2.Specification
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito

class TestSpec extends Specification with Mockito { def is = s2"""
  test $e1
"""

  def e1 = {
    val mockedService = mock[Service]
    mockedService.invoke(1, 2, 3).answers { (params, mock) =>
      params match {
        case Array(a, b: Int, c) => b + 2
      }
    }
    mockedService.invoke(1, 2, 3) must_== 4
  }
}

trait Service {
  def invoke(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, arg3: Int) = 1
}
```